# Why does Redis run slower in Docker than it does natively?

Tags: docker, redis

I noticed that Redis works much slower with docker than it does natively. What could this be related to?

Here is my tests on VPS with 1 CPU core / 1 GB RAM / Ubuntu 22.04.

**Native Redis on the host** (the fastest)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis (redis_version:6.0.16)
redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
```

```
PING_INLINE: 23004.37 requests per second
PING_BULK: 21915.41 requests per second
SET: 23792.53 requests per second
GET: 22867.60 requests per second
INCR: 23894.86 requests per second
LPUSH: 25252.53 requests per second
RPUSH: 24551.93 requests per second
LPOP: 24414.06 requests per second
RPOP: 24307.24 requests per second
SADD: 23512.82 requests per second
HSET: 24746.35 requests per second
SPOP: 22758.31 requests per second
ZADD: 23969.32 requests per second
ZPOPMIN: 22701.47 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 24113.82 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 17531.56 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 7954.18 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 6106.12 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 5296.89 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 30012.00 requests per second
```

**Redis in Docker tested outside the container** (the slowest)

```
docker pull redis:6.0.17
docker run --name redis -p 6378:6379 -d redis:6.0.17
redis-benchmark -q -n 100000 -p 6378
```

```
PING_INLINE: 7548.31 requests per second
PING_BULK: 7623.69 requests per second
SET: 7474.96 requests per second
GET: 7474.96 requests per second
INCR: 7488.95 requests per second
LPUSH: 7443.25 requests per second
RPUSH: 7487.27 requests per second
LPOP: 7401.92 requests per second
RPOP: 7163.84 requests per second
SADD: 7252.16 requests per second
HSET: 7192.17 requests per second
SPOP: 7217.61 requests per second
ZADD: 7331.38 requests per second
ZPOPMIN: 7597.63 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 7392.62 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 6248.05 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 6377.55 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 5748.45 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 4578.75 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 6895.60 requests per second
```

**Running the test inside the container** (slightly slower than on the host, but I don't run my app inside the container)

```
docker exec -it redis sh
redis-benchmark -q -n 100000
```

```
PING_INLINE: 22416.50 requests per second
PING_BULK: 21654.40 requests per second
SET: 23413.72 requests per second
GET: 22351.36 requests per second
INCR: 22784.23 requests per second
LPUSH: 24467.83 requests per second
RPUSH: 23651.84 requests per second
LPOP: 23781.21 requests per second
RPOP: 23691.07 requests per second
SADD: 22747.95 requests per second
HSET: 24301.34 requests per second
SPOP: 22172.95 requests per second
ZADD: 24301.34 requests per second
ZPOPMIN: 22578.46 requests per second
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 24177.95 requests per second
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 13817.88 requests per second
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 7212.93 requests per second
LRANGE_500 (first 450 elements): 5898.31 requests per second
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 4890.45 requests per second
MSET (10 keys): 29154.52 requests per second
```

**Running the test inside other container with docker compose** (average performance)

```
Dockerfile
FROM redis:6.0.17
CMD redis-benchmark -q -n 100000 -h redis

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
  redis:
    image: "redis:6.0.17"
```

```
PING_INLINE: 16173.38 requests per second, p50=1.495 msec
PING_MBULK: 15172.20 requests per second, p50=1.503 msec
SET: 15989.77 requests per second, p50=1.503 msec
GET: 15701.05 requests per second, p50=1.511 msec
INCR: 16121.23 requests per second, p50=1.487 msec
LPUSH: 16428.46 requests per second, p50=1.495 msec
RPUSH: 14630.58 requests per second, p50=1.639 msec
LPOP: 15542.43 requests per second, p50=1.567 msec
RPOP: 15518.31 requests per second, p50=1.551 msec
SADD: 14900.91 requests per second, p50=1.567 msec
HSET: 15176.81 requests per second, p50=1.575 msec
SPOP: 14918.69 requests per second, p50=1.583 msec
ZADD: 15855.40 requests per second, p50=1.543 msec
ZPOPMIN: 15248.55 requests per second, p50=1.551 msec
LPUSH (needed to benchmark LRANGE): 16466.33 requests per second, p50=1.495 msec
LRANGE_100 (first 100 elements): 10330.58 requests per second, p50=2.423 msec
LRANGE_300 (first 300 elements): 5361.07 requests per second, p50=4.671 msec
LRANGE_500 (first 500 elements): 3863.99 requests per second, p50=6.191 msec
LRANGE_600 (first 600 elements): 3718.99 requests per second, p50=6.559 msec
MSET (10 keys): 20618.56 requests per second, p50=1.415 msec
```

As you can see from the tests, every time you use Docker, the Redis performance slows down.
But the main selling point of Docker is that it does not have a negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume the different results are due to the network setup of the containers.

For *host -> container* communication with published ports, docker needs to do network address translation(NAT) to route your request. If you do `ss -tlpn` you will see not redis listening on the published port but dockerd. The docker daemon then will forward the connection to the correct container port. To do this it needs to keep track of all the connection information and rewrite every IP packet send to the port.

For *container -> container* communication docker does not need to do the whole NAT but still has some considerable routing logic. Depending on your configuration this could be for example configured in iptables.

To give you a quick overview over how this works:
Docker sets up a [network namespace](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html) for every container. A bare network namespace has no network connectivity without further modification.
To add connectivity to the container Docker creates a [veth pair](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html) and moves one end into the network namespace and configures IP addresses for the veth interfaces.
This is done for both containers.
Now if those containers want to talk to each other docker needs to set up correct routing in iptables for both veth interfaces.

I am not sure about all the details, because my investigation into all of this was quite a while back.

As already suggested by @sks147 you could try to run the container with [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) to disable network isolation.